# Set jquery delay from html data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set individual duration times from a value in the html that the text is displayed before displaying the next. I thought maybe I could do something with setting a variable (howlong) for the jquery .delay, but it's only getting the value by the first "data-howlongtime" for the rest of them. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnc5L1dg/2/).  What am I doing wrong besides everything?

```
<div id="aboutid" data-howlongtime="10000">
  <p class="abouts">Less delay</p>
</div>
<div id="aboutid" data-howlongtime="20000">
  <p class="abouts">Long delay</p>
</div>

<style>.abouts {display: none;}</style>

<script>
var delayabout=1700;
var howlong = $('#aboutid').data('data-howlongtime');

(function() {

    var abouts = $(".abouts");
    var aboutIndex = -1;

    function showNextabout() {
        ++aboutIndex;
        abouts.eq(aboutIndex % abouts.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(howlong)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextabout);
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        showNextabout();
    }, delayabout);

})();
</script>
```

Comment: id's should be unique, if you don't follow that you'll get unintended behavior.Try changing `aboutid` to a class and then get each `data-howlongtime`

Comment: use a class instead of an id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you are actually taking the howlongtime at the top, one time only, you need to check it for every iteration.

```
var delayabout = 1000;

(function() {

  var abouts = $(".abouts");
  var aboutIndex = -1;

  function showNextabout() {
    ++aboutIndex;
    var $about = abouts.eq(aboutIndex % abouts.length),
       howLong = $about.parents('div#aboutid').data('howlongtime');
      $about.fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(howLong)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextabout);
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    showNextabout();
  }, delayabout);

})();
```